# Flask wtforms jquery validation

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, forms, flask

I use wtforms in my Flask app and I would like validate form in browser via jquery.

My code of form is

```
class LoginForm(Form):
   email = StringField('Email',[validators.DataRequired(message='Sorry, this is a required field.')])
   password = PasswordField('Password', [validators.DataRequired()])
```

but validate not found .

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "validate not found"?

Comment: I wrote wrong,
validate is found if i use form.validate()

but i would like realtime validation, something which is in HTML5 for example Required file, if I don´t fill form and i will send it validation must show message that I must fill input.
Form doesn´t send while I fill input.

Comment: HTML5 doesn't require jQuery for its validation. You just need to set the attributes like [`required`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-required-attribute) and [`type`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#states-of-the-type-attribute). What does your template look like?

Answer (score 0):

this question is kind of hard to understand what your intention is.

what do you mean by using jquery? You could create a route and then send the serialized form back to that route and return the data.

```
var validate = function() {
  $.post("{{ url_for('validate') }}", $('form').serialize(), function(errors) {
    alert(errors);
    // update the dom with the errors however you want.
  });
}
```

Then in your route, you can do something to this effect.

```
@app.route('/yourform/validate', methods=['POST'])
def validate():
  form = LoginForm(request.form)
  form.validate()
  return jsonify(form.errors)
```

Then you can pretty much attach your javascript function to some sort of event, like `$('input').blur(validate)`

Comment: Yes i want only check if is form fill correct. If is, so form can by send but if is not, so must show error message and form can not by send. In the beast way error message will by like this [link](http://tylergaw.com/articles/assets/post_image_htmlFormErrors_demo01.jpg)